# Is it necessary to close Xcode project when installing pods?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

Let's say I want to install firebase pod, I add it to Podfile, next I have to run `pod install` at the terminal, is it necessary to close the project?

Answer (score 4):

If you have the `.xcodeproj` file open, yes. You need to close it and then open the new `.xcworkspace` file after cocoa pods has done its thing.

If you have a workspace already you theoretically don't need to close it but I generally do to keep Xcode from being grumpy.

Comment: Yep, it usually works for me to keep it open, but sometimes Xcode will lose track of the Pods and need to be reopened or even restarted.